# Whats the meaning of: Separator.Iterator.Element == Self.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element

Tags: swift, swift3

What's the meaning of:

```
Separator.Iterator.Element == Self.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element
```

in [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1690077-joined) (Swift standard library) swift instance method declaration?

```
func joined<Separator>(separator: Separator) -> 
JoinedSequence<Array<Element>> where Separator : Sequence, 
Separator.Iterator.Element == Self.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element
```

and here is the example from Apple:

```
let nestedNumbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let joined = nestedNumbers.joined(separator: [-1, -2])
print(Array(joined))
// Prints "[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, 7, 8, 9]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joined(separator:)` is available to call on sequences of sequences:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Sequence {

  // ...

  public func joined<Separator : Sequence>(separator: Separator) -> JoinedSequence<Self>
    where Separator.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element
}
```

It takes a `separator:` parameter, which itself must be a sequence. The constraint `Separator.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element` simply means that the separator's element type must be the same as the *inner* element type of the sequence that `joined(separator)` is called on.

For example, you're calling it on a `[[Int]]`. It's `Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element` (the element type of the array's element type), is `Int`. Therefore the separator you use must be a sequence of `Int`s, which `[Int]` is.

Try passing in a `[String]` for the separator – you'll get a compiler error because `String` ≠ `Int`, and therefore doesn't meet the requirement `Separator.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element`.

Comment: Great, but you mean in swift when we want to say a and b have the same type we can say it like this?: **a == b**

Comment: @Jami2 When we're talking about generic constraints, then yes – that's the syntax to say two given types must be equivalent. Take a look at the [generic where clauses section](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID192) of the language guide for more info :)